# How to build a ortoghonal basis from a vector?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, linear-algebra, orthogonal

anybody know how I can build a orthogonal base using only a vector? I have a vector in the form v1 = [a b -a -b]', where 'a' and 'b' are real numbers. I did try build in the "adhoc way" but, nothing, I only got two orthogonal vectors:

v1 = [a  b -a -b]'
v2 = [a -b  a -b]'

I need more two vectors to complete the orthogonal basis {v1, v2, v3, v4}. Anybody can help me?

Thanks...

Comment: Gram-Schmidt is your jam: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: An orthonormal basis for what?  If you only have one vector, you can only build a 1D vector space with v1 as its basis vector.  You can normalize your vector v1 and be done with it.  If you want a basis for a 4D space, you will need 4 linearly independent vectors unless you're able to provide some additional information about how you plan to derive those other vectors.

Answer (score 2):

I can't do it for you in Mathematica, but in MATLAB at least, I'd do it like this...

```
syms a b
null([a b -a -b])
ans =
[ -b/a, 1, b/a]
[    1, 0,   0]
[    0, 1,   0]
[    0, 0,   1]
```

The columns of this array are orthogonal to the original vector, and span the nullspace.

Answer (score 2):

v3 = [b a b a]',  v4 = [b -a -b a]' has a pleasing symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

You can augment with an identity matrix and orthogonalize that set of vectors, with your given one at the front. Here is an example.

```
SeedRandom[1111];
{a, b} = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 2];
vec = {a, b, -a, -b}
mat = Join[{vec}, IdentityMatrix[Length[vec]]];

(* Out[39]= {-8, 5, 8, -5} *)

orthog = Drop[Orthogonalize[mat], -1]

(* Out[62]= {{-4*Sqrt[2/89], 5/Sqrt[178], 
  4*Sqrt[2/89], -(5/Sqrt[178])}, 
   {Sqrt[57/89], 20/Sqrt[5073], 32/Sqrt[5073], -(20/Sqrt[5073])}, 
   {0, Sqrt[89/114], -20*Sqrt[2/5073], 25/Sqrt[10146]}, 
   {0, 0, 5/Sqrt[89], 8/Sqrt[89]}} *)
```